# formatting \makeindex in class file

Tags: document-classes, makeindex

I'm relatively new to LaTeX and I am trying to learn how to create a class of document based on a book class. I can add an index and have it printed when I compile, as long as I leave everything at default. when I try to pass arguments to `makeindex` I get an error (this `\makeindex` becomes this `\makeindex[intoc, columns=3]`) and this is the error I get:

> Missing \begin{document}. \makeindex[

This is my class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{MyStyle}[2022/08/29 Baseline book style class]
%load the base class for New class
\LoadClass[12]{book}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Make index 
\RequirePackage{makeidx}
\makeindex[intoc, columns=3]
```

it compiles and works if I remove

> [intoc, columns=3]

this is the main tex file:

```
\documentclass{MyStyle}[2022/08/29]

\title{Style Guide}
\author{Daniel Fonseca Corradini De Ferrand}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    
%not my text
        You may have several mobile devices that you want to
        \index{sync} with windows 7.\index{remote} devices are seen
        by \index{Windows} 7 as removable \index{storage devices}.
        
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

How can I pass arguments to `\makeindex` from within my class file?

Comment: The options you request are not provided by the `makeindex` package, but they *are* available with `imakeidx`.  Perhaps you could try that.

Comment: Thanks all I had to do was change \RequirePackage{makeidx} to imakeidx. If you post an answer I'll set it as resolved

Comment: I think this is undoubtedly covered by several other questions already, so this is more likely a dupe, but I don't have time to look for it right now.  I'm glad that was all that needed to be done.